# multiprocessing with python, poor performance in a rather simple case

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

the following procedure generates a big list (permutations) from which a given quantity is computed. I've used multiprocessing to split the task among different threads as follows:

```
def multiprocessing_mci(arr, Smo, num_threads):
   import multiprocessing as mp

   permutations = unique_permutations(arr)

   
   chunk_size = int(np.ceil(len(permutations) / num_threads))
   permutations_chunks = [permutations[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(permutations), chunk_size)]

   
   pool = mp.Pool(processes = num_threads)

   results = []
   for chunk in permutations_chunks:
      result = pool.starmap(compute_iring, [(order, Smo) for order in chunk])
      results.extend(result)
   
   trace = sum(results)

   return trace
```

I run the code in a 8 core linux machine. When I setup num_threads=4, I see at some point 4 processes, but each of them is using up to 200% of cpu (according to top), so the machine is fully loaded.
I've checked that executing the code with taskset -c 0-3 python run.py does the job.
Now I see from other threads that OMP_NUM_THREADS env variable should be set to 1, so I guess this happens because my procedure "compute_iring" uses numpy,right? That should solve the first issue.

The second issue is performance; it is pretty bad: the speedup is just 1.4 for 2 threads and 2.3 for 4 threads. I was expecting much better performance because the parallelization is trivial in this case (each element of the list in permutations contributes the same way to "trace" via "compute_iring"). Most likely i did something dumb here.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `starmap` returns results in order; use `imap_unordered` if (and clearly when) you don't care about the order. You should show what `compute_iring` does, too.

Comment: Also, "among different threads" -- no, you're spawning different _processes_, and that incurs IPC overhead.

Comment: manually dividing the chunks is wrong, just pass all the data to something like `imap_unordered` without chunking, this has the least overhead, python devs have good defaults.

Comment: Please provide the input used in testing. The disparity between your expectation of run time and the actual run time could be caused by using small input, in which case the setup (starting processes, IPC etc.) could represent a larger amount of run time, proportionally. Does the run time trend more towards your expectation when the size of the input increases?

Comment: don't do the chunking and then pass to starmap... map, starmap, etc *does the chunking for you*.

Comment: Note, you are actually just passing smaller chunks that get chunked again when you call `map`. If you *are* going to do the chunking yourself, then make sure your function works on a chunk (not an individual item) and use `apply_async` then join

Comment: You may want to give each process more work to do (like a whole chunk?), as other mentioned, overhead of starting process may be the reason you do not have close to x4 speed-up. Also, make sure you first improve performance of `compute_iring` function first, using multiprocessing is one of the last steps of improving performance

Comment: Thank you all very much for the hints. I'm complketely new to pythn and mutiprocessing and do not know exactly how to modify it , but I see the code is unefficient.  Thanks!